# rbind and bind_rows :not able bind rows the way I want

Tags: r, dplyr

I have seven `data.frame`s named `STEP1.df`, `STEP2.df`,......,`STEP7.df`.
Each dataframe has two columns, one is a numeric and another is of Date.Time format. These `data.frame`s have 44 rows. I am trying to make a single `data.frame` by binding them together.
The way I tried are:

```
do.call("rbind", list(STEP1.df, STEP2.df, STEP3.df, STEP4.df, STEP5.df, STEP6.df,STEP7.df))

bind_rows (list(STEP1.df, STEP2.df, STEP3.df, STEP4.df, STEP5.df, STEP6.df,STEP7.df)
```

The issue is that above code creates 14 columns (2 for each `data.frame`s) and puts

first `data.frame` STEP1.df in Column 1 and 2 / Row 1 to 44,
second `data.frame` STEP2.df in Column 3 and 4 / Row 45 to 88
...

and so on.

The way I wanted was to put all in just two columns A and B with STEP1.df spanning from Row 1 to 44, STEP2.df in Column A and B in Row 45 to 88 and so on...

Is this issue due to the Date.Time format column?
[image: Screenshot of what I described]

Comment: Possibly due to different column names.  Change them to the same column name and test it

Comment: A small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/210673) would be very helpful. Try with just two data frames and just a couple rows each, and include the data with dput so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @akrun Keeping constant column names for each df worked..Thanks a lot.